# Problems with modeling a POS (Point-of-sale) system

Tags: sql, sql-server

At first a apologize for being a beginner in databases. I'm developing a POS system and I'm having some trouble in modeling the part of the system which controls the customer's account. I'll try to explain the requirements below:

The customer has a unique credit account;

This credit account will have zero or several sales;

Each sale will be one or several products.

These are the mainly requirements. What I'm trying developing is a way you can, using the system, query the customer's account and see the sales and their respective products (grouped by dates for example) the customer purchased on that sale.

I've already taken a look on the kinds of database relationships, but I cannot find a solution on using the many-to-many relationship. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to the part you've having a problem with? Do you have a part made solution?

Comment: You need one-to-many relationship from account to sales and many-to-many relation from sales to products. You have to use additional table for last relationship, I would call that "sale lines" or similar - where you save sale id, product id, quantity, price etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it from what I understand is you're going to have to separate this out into data tables

From your description we can identify some entities,

- Customer
- CreditAccount
- SaleOrder
- Product

Once you had this set up, you could create a query to do what you just described, short of doing it for you, this would be a good start for a suitable solution.

Comment: I liked the Arvo's answer, but my question following his idea is how I can query afterwards. My main question is how I can transmit an "array-based" modeling among the customer's account and the sales the customer did. Each sale will have too many products. Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: On my modeling, that's the part which causes me trouble: the product-sales-account relationship.

Comment: That's why you need some kind of saleOrder table, this works as a join table allowing a customer to have many orders, and that order to have many products or sale items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tables such as:

CreditAccount

Product

your sale will most likely result in an Invoice table (or a Sale table - I don't know your business well).

This table will resolve the many-to-many between the Product table and the CreditAccount table.

The Invoice table may look like this (it may vary greatly based on your other needs):

- InvoiceNumber (A good candidate for primary key, business rules required for pros and cons)
- CreditAccount_FK (Foreign key pointing to the primary key in CreditAccount table)
- Product_FK (Foreing key pointing to the primary key in Product table)
- Other sale or invoice columns such as branch, sales person, date, time, tax, payment method, etc.

You could choose to define a unique key on the pair(CreditAccount_FK, Product_FK). If you don't have a unique InvoiceNumber, you may use the combination above to be the primary key.